# Getting user_forbidden when retrieving folder details from skydrive api

Tags: onedrive

I am facing an issue where a user is able to add his Skydrive account using OAuth, but when I am trying to get folder details (`/skydrive/me/files`) with Skydrive Live API I am getting this response

```
{"error": {
  "code": "user_forbidden", 
  "message": "The user's account has been disabled in SkyDrive."}
```

When will I get this error ?

Thanks,

Anurag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User's SKyDrive account was disabled by Microsoft due to inactivity, although his live account was still active.
During oauth they will not check for Skydrive account status. so client should check for account status after oauth and prompt to user if account has been disable.